# I want this function called donate to transfer all remaining funds in the contract to the charity address When is called

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I want this function called donate to transfer all remaining funds in the contract to the charity address When is called

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Contract {
    address payable public a;
    address  payable public owner  ;
    constructor(address _charity) {
        owner   = payable (msg.sender);
        a = payable(_charity);
    }
    event Received(address, uint);
     receive() external payable {
    emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
    function tip() public payable {
      payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
  }
  function donate() public payable {
     a.transfer(msg.value);
   }
}
```

When I run the test, the code doesn't pass. It says:

> donating should add the donations to the charity balance expected '0' to equal '1000000000000000000'

Test code:

```
const { assert } = require('chai');
describe('Contract', function () {
    const charity = ethers.Wallet.createRandom().address;
    const donation = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
    let contract;
    let owner;
    let tipper;
    before(async () => {
        const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Contract");
        contract = await Contract.deploy(charity);
        await contract.deployed();

        owner = ethers.provider.getSigner(0);
        await owner.sendTransaction({ to: contract.address, value: donation });
        tipper = ethers.provider.getSigner(1);
    });

    it('should store the owner', async () => {
        const _owner = await contract.owner.call();
        assert.equal(_owner, await owner.getAddress());
    });

    it('should receive the initial donation', async () => {
        const balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(contract.address);
        assert(balance.eq(donation), "expected the ether to be received");
    });

    describe('after two .25 ether tips', () => {
        const tip = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.25");
        let balanceBefore;
        before(async () => {
            balanceBefore = await ethers.provider.getBalance(await owner.getAddress());
            await contract.connect(tipper).tip({ value: tip });
            await contract.connect(tipper).tip({ value: tip });
        });

        it('should add .5 ether to the owners balance', async () => {
            const balanceAfter = await ethers.provider.getBalance(await owner.getAddress());
            assert.equal(balanceAfter.sub(balanceBefore).toString(), tip.mul(2).toString());
        });
    });

    describe('after donating', () => {
        before(async () => {
            await contract.connect(tipper).donate();
        });

        it('should add the donations to the charity balance', async () => {
            const _donation = await ethers.provider.getBalance(charity);
            assert.equal(_donation.toString(), donation.toString());
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you send what is remaining funds in the contract. So instead of what is send to the contract :

```
function donate() public payable{
  a.transfer(address(this).balance);
    selfdestruct(owner);
}
```

Comment: Please share any relevant code [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).